# JQ function hover()

Tags: jquery

I need to make an element selection when the cursor sticks on it for 3 seconds. In the above example, it turns out to select an element, but there are problems with elements that have a common ancestor, the timer is not reset to them, but when the "confirmed" class is present, everything works as planned, you need to make the timer reset.

Text translation...

```
<style>
  .elem {
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-out, .2s outline ease-in-out !important;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease-out, .2s outline ease-in-out !important;
    transition: background-color .3s ease-out, .2s outline ease-in-out !important;
    background-color: #bcd5eb !important;
    outline: 1px solid #1d66bb !important;
    color: #333 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
  }

  .confirmed {
    background-color: #fc7169 !important;
    outline: 1px solid #dd345f !important;
    color: #333 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
  }
</style>
<ul>
  <li>menu 1</li>
  <li>menu 2</li>
  <li>menu 3</li>
  <li>menu 4</li>
  <li>menu 5</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <span>flow 1</span><br>
  <span>flow 2</span><br>
  <span>flow 3</span><br>
  <span>flow 4</span><br>
  <span>flow 5</span><br>
</div>
<br>
<span>flow 1</span><br>
<span>flow 2</span><br>
<span>flow 3</span><br>
<span>flow 4</span><br>
<span>flow 5</span><br>
<script>
  $('*').hover(
    function(event) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();

      event.stopPropagation();

      $('.elem').removeClass('elem');

      $(this).addClass('elem');

      $.data(this, 'timer',
        setTimeout($.proxy(
          function() {
            $('.confirmed').removeClass('confirmed');

            $('.elem').addClass('confirmed')
          }, this
        ), 2500)
      );
    },

    function() {
      clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

      $('.elem').removeClass('elem')

    }
  );
</script>
```

EXAMPLE 
https://jsfiddle.net/module/6k8zqpv4/3/

Comment: Are you looking to only have your hovered element selected and not the group of elements? Why not add a mouse out event that cancels your style?

Comment: The timer is not reset if there is no "confirmed" class in the document.
The class "confirmed" is first assigned to a random element under the cursors after 3 seconds when the cursor is on <body>

Comment: occurs after a hard reset page

Comment: so As I understood, you need to select an item if the mouse is hover it for more than 3 second, but what will happen when it will hover on some other item for more than 3 seconds? do we need to select that one and deselect old one, or do we need to select both'?

Comment: ( 1 ) do we need to select that one and deselect old one.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that the .hover() function is a wrapper for the .mouseenter () and .mouseleave() functions.
To work correctly, you need to use the functions .mouseover() and .mouseout().

```
$( document.body )
    .on( 'mouseover', '*', function( event ) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        event.stopPropagation();

        $( '.elem' ).removeClass( 'elem' );

        $( this ).addClass( 'elem' );

        $.data( this, 'timer', setTimeout( $.proxy(
            function() {
                 $( '.confirmed' ).removeClass( 'confirmed' );

                 $( '.elem' ).addClass( 'confirmed' )                
            }, this 
        ), 2500 ) );
   })

   .on( 'mouseout', '*', function( event ) {
       clearTimeout( $.data( this, 'timer' ) );

       $( '.elem' ).removeClass( 'elem' )
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about manually resetting the timers of all parent elements on mouseout? It no longer experiences the problem where the timer continues to run down when waving the mouse over a group when there is no ".confirmed" element. Your javascript would look like this:

```
$( '*' ).hover(
  function( event ) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();

    event.stopPropagation();

    $( '.elem' ).removeClass( 'elem' );

    $( this ).addClass( 'elem' );

    $.data( this, 'timer', 
           setTimeout( $.proxy(
      function() {
        $( '.confirmed' ).removeClass( 'confirmed' );

        $( '.elem' ).addClass( 'confirmed' )                
      }, this 
    ), 2500 )
          );
  },

  function() {
    clearTimeout( $.data( this, 'timer' ) );

    // new code
    $(this).parents().each(function(index, parent){
      clearTimeout($(parent).data("timer"));
    });

    $( '.elem' ).removeClass( 'elem' )

  }
);
```